# Java Loop - Removing numbers that has 4 or more of the same digits

Tags: java, loops

I was wondering how one would create a loop where it would print all the numbers from 200000 - 900000 and remove all the digits such as 222244.

So far this is all I have:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class alg {

    public void algorithm(){
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        PrintWriter file = null;
        try {
            file = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int x;
        for (x = 200000; x < 900000; x++){
            file.println(x);
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 4 equal digits in a row or in total?

Comment: Both. Sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: about your exceptions: provide proper filepath.

Comment: Check the placement of your curly brackets. Right now `file.close();` does not belong to any method.

Comment: May I ask for what real-world application you need such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// return true if integer has 4 or more of same digit, otherwise false
static boolean check4(int i) {
    int[] charCounts = new int[10];
    for (char c : String.valueOf(i).toCharArray()) {
        if (++charCounts[c-'0'] == 4) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I finally got my program to work. I appreciate your code. It is simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no mathematical solutions for this, you need to parse the numbers:

```
int x;
// loop through all the numbers
for (x = 200000; x < 900000; x++) {
    // for each number x, check digits 0-9
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        // convert current number x to a String
        final String originalNumber = Integer.toString(x);
        // replace all digits i in current number x and check if the lenth was decreased by 4 or more
        if (originalNumber.replaceAll(Integer.toString(i)).length() <= originalNumber.length() - 4) {
            // if so, print the current number x to your file
            file.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

I think there are better solutions but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. It is essentially a method to stringify the integer, break it into a `Character[]` and uses the `Collections.frequency()` method to check your condition. It will return `true` if the number has 4 or more of the same digit.

```
private static boolean containsFourOfSameDigit(Integer x) {
    final int threshold = 4; //Change for 3, 2, whatever you want.
    String s = x.toString();

    /* Populate a char array and then list with all digits */
    Character[] ch = new Character[s.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        ch[i] = s.charAt(i);

    ArrayList<Character> allDigits = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(ch));
    HashSet<Character> uniqueDigits = new HashSet<Character>(allDigits);

    for(Character c : uniqueDigits)
        if(Collections.frequency(allDigits, c) >= threshold)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

`System.out.println(containsFourOfSameDigit(200000));` will print `true`, as will your 222244 example. Note this doesn't complete your program, it is just the boolean method you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using java `Pattern` class with some kind of pattern like:
`[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}`.
In loop you could just call `String stringified = yourNumber + "";`
and that match it with ALREADY compiled pattern.